# Sprite rotate and move direction issue

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

I am developing a game using cocos2d-x v3.3.

In my game play I am having a straight line sprite image which is rotating continusaly at 360 angle. On the edge of line there is another ball sprite.

So what I want in my game is whenever I touch the screen it should start rotating and on touch end the ball on line edge should move in the direction of the line pointing.

Comment: please edit the question to provide some code. Let us see what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you..
My code is here.

```
Circle1 = Sprite::create("circleT.png");
Circle1->setPosition(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/3.8);
this->addChild(Circle1,1);


line = Sprite::create("line.png");
line->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0.5, 1.0));
line->setPosition(Circle1->getBoundingBox().size.width/2,0);
Circle1->addChild(line,1);

bullet = Sprite::create("bullet.png");
bullet->setPosition(Vec2 (winSize.width/2,winSize.height/4));
this->addChild(bullet);    

Point offset    = ccpSub(touchLocation, bullet->getPosition());
float   ratio     = offset.x/offset.y;
int     targetY   =  winSize.height - bullet->getContentSize().height;
float disY  = -(bullet->getPositionY() - targetY);
int     targetX   = (disY * ratio) + bullet->getPositionX();
CCPoint  touchPoint = ccp(targetX*20,targetY*20);


MoveTo *bulletmove = MoveTo::create(1, Vec2(touchPoint));
bullet->runAction(bulletmove);
```

On TouchBegin I call the method of rotate of circle and now in the code my bullet is going on the touch location. so want bullet should go in the direction of line.